# Expected value of $Z=X_1+X_2$ if $X_1<X_3$.and $Z=X_1$ if $X_3\leq X_1$

Tags: conditional-expectation, expected-value

Let $X_1, X_2$ and $X_3$ three independent random variables with PDF $f_{X_i}(x)$.

I would like to compute the average of random vraible saying $Z$. But here i have two events.
The two events are $\phi$ and $\bar{\phi}$

$$
\phi=\{X_3\leq X_1\},
$$

and

$$\bar{\phi}=\{X_1< X_3\}.$$

I would like to get the expected value of $Z=X_1$ if the event $\phi$ occur

$$
E[X_1 ;
 \phi],
$$
 and the expected value of $Z=X_1+X_2$ if the event $\bar{\phi}$ occur

$$
E[X_1+X_2;
\bar{\phi}].
$$

Finally I get 
$$
E[Z]=E[X_1;
{\phi}]+E[X_1+X_2;
\bar{\phi}].
$$
 Thanks.

Comment: $\newcommand{\I}{\operatorname{\mathbb{I}}}\newcommand{\P}{\operatorname{\mathbb{P}}}\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{\mathbb{E}}}$What you want is not $\color{red}{\cap}$, but rather $\color{blue}{\I}$ (indicator function). That is, $\E\left[X\mid A\right] = \dfrac{\E[X \I(A)]}{\P(A)}$. For example, $\E[X_1 + X_2 \mid X_1 < X_3] = \dfrac{\E\left[(X_1 + X_2)\I(X_1 < X_3)\right]}{\P(X_1 < X_3)}$.

Comment: Hi I did not explain every thing, But now I add all my problem.

Comment: i am not a statician or mathematician but i want to share my thoughts in a primitive way. we are asked average of  x1 given that x1>=x3.. so we are asked average of x1 but we are sure that minimum value it can take is x3. so answer is integration of function from x3 to max value. in second part, because these are random variables, x2 does not care about any relation between x1 and x3. so answer is e(x2) + integral of function from min value to x3... this comment may not fit for standards of this site and it may be wrong, but still i wanted to write it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Z = (X_1 + X_2) \,[X_1 < X_3] + X_1 \,[X_3 \leq X_1]$, then
$$Z = X_1 + X_2 \,[X_1 < X_3], \\
\operatorname{E}(Z) =
\operatorname{E}(X_1) +
 \operatorname{E}(X_2 \mid X_1 < X_3) \operatorname{P}(X_1 < X_3) =\\
\operatorname{E}(X_1) +
\operatorname{E}(X_2) \operatorname{P}(X_1 < X_3).$$

Comment: Is $E[X_1, X_3<X_1]=\int_{x_1=0}^{\infty}x_1f_{X_1}(x_1)\left(\int_{x_3=0}^{x_1}f_{X_3}(x_3)dx_3\right)dx_1$

Comment: Do you mean the conditional expectation $\operatorname{E}(X_1 \mid X_3 < X_1)$? If so,
$$\operatorname{E}(X_1 \mid X_3 < X_1) =
\frac {\operatorname{E}(X_1 \,[X_3 < X_1])} {\operatorname{P}(X_3 < X_1)},$$
where the square brackets are a [different notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) for the indicator function. The numerator is equal to the integral that you wrote, assuming that the pdfs are zero on $(-\infty, 0)$. But if I understand correctly, you're looking for the unconditional expectation of $Z$.

Comment: Ok is not the conditional I mean $$E(X_1 [X_3<X_1])=\int_{x_1=0}^{\infty}x_1f_{X_1}(x)\int_{x_3=0}^{x_1}f_{X_3}(x_3)dx_3 dx_1$$

Comment: Can you help me in  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3152009 please.

Comment: I see, the last formula is correct. You can write out $\operatorname{E}((X_1 + X_2) \,[X_1 < X_3])$ in the same way and verify that you get the same result as in the answer.

Comment: So  $$E(X1[X3<X1])=\int_{x_1=0}^{\infty} x_1f_{X_1}(x_1)\int_{x_3=0}^{x_1}f_{X_3}(x_3)dx_3dx_1$$

Comment: Yes, that's the formula I was referring to, it is correct.

Comment: Ok Thank you so much.