# Find the probability $P\{X_1<X_3<X_2<\alpha-X_3\}$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

> Let $X_1, X_2$ and $X_3$ three independent random variables with pdf and cdf 
>   $f_{X_i}(x_i)$ and $F_{X_i}(x_i)$ for $x_i\geq 0$, receptively.
>   Using CDFs and PDFs of $X_i$, find the probability $$P\{X_1<X_3<X_2<\alpha-X_3\}.$$

Is it 
$$
P\{X_1<X_3<X_2<\alpha-X_3\} \\
=\int_{x_3=0}^{\infty}
\int_{x_2=0}^{\alpha-x_3}
\int_{x_3=0}^{x_2}
\int_{x_1=0}^{x_3} f_{X_1}(x_1)\, \mathrm{d}x_1
f_{X_3}(x_3)\, \mathrm{d}x_3
f_{X_2}(x_2)\, \mathrm{d}x_2
f_{X_3}(x_3)\, \mathrm{d}x_3~,
$$
or
$$
P\{X_1<X_3<X_2<\alpha-X_3\}=
\int_{x_3=0}^{\infty}
\int_{x_2=0}^{\alpha-x_3}
\int_{x_1=0}^{x_3} f_{X_1}(x_1) \,\mathrm{d} x_1
f_{X_2}(x_2) \,\mathrm{d} x_2
f_{X_3}(x_3) \,\mathrm{d} x_3 ~?
$$
Thanks.

Comment: You  seem to assume all $X_i\ge 0$,  $x_2$ is missing a lower limit on both expressions.  The second expression looks right.  The first is weird.

Comment: The inequalities imply $2 X_3 < \alpha$, therefore
$$\operatorname{P}(X_1 < X_3 < X_2 < \alpha - X_3) = \\
\int_0^{\alpha/2} \int_{x_3}^{\alpha - x_3} \int_0^{x_3}
 f_{X_1}(x_1) f_{X_2}(x_2) f_{X_3}(x_3) \,dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 \,[\alpha > 0].$$

Comment: Why, how do you did simplify?

Comment: Ignore $x_1$ for now and draw the region $x_3 < x_2 < \alpha - x_3$ on the plane.